# What does this sentence mean? And what does "by the day" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> a worker who has learned a handicraft or trade and is qualified ***to
>   work at it usually for another by the day.*** ([Webster](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?book=Student&va=journeyman))

Does the bold part of sentence means: "...to work at the profession (what he has learned) usually for another person day by day."

Am I correct? Or does it mean something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A journeyman was paid **for each day** of his work, as opposed to some master craftsman who would be paid after he has completed a project.

Let's explore the etymology:

> [Journey](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=journey&allowed_in_frame=0): A day's work (from mid-14th century), from Latin *diurnus*, "of one day".

So, a ***journey***-man was initially a man whose work was measured in days and paid for accordingly.

This initial sense of the word turned somewhat obsolete by 1816, judging by this dictionary entry:

> [Journeyman](http://books.google.ru/books?id=f1gKAQAAMAAJ&dq=journeyman%20%22by%20the%20day%22&hl=ru&pg=PA305#v=onepage&q=journeyman%20%22by%20the%20day%22&f=false): a hired workman; a workman hired by the day. They were called *journeymen* that wrought with others by the day, though now by statute it be extended to those that covenant to work in their occupation by the year.

Another quote (*[Two Carpenters, 2006](http://books.google.ru/books?id=5P3e5brhvRMC&lpg=PA15&dq=journeyman%20wage%20day&hl=ru&pg=PA15#v=onepage&q=journeyman%20wage%20day&f=false)*):

> A *journeyman* was a *day-wage laborer* who usually worked under the general direction of a master.

Comment: Nice one - & these days we are paid by the hour, but have zero-hour contracts… sometimes we ought to wish for the old days… & scurvy... ;)